# Find matching Document based on parameters stored in the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a challenge while developing a small adserver with targeting options.

Given that we have a collection of campaigns with the following parameters in the mongoose model:

```
new MongoOse.Schema({
image: String,
filters: [new MongoOse.Schema({
                uid: String,
                type: {
                    type: String,
                    enum: ['curr_avg', 'target_avg', 'subject_id']
                },
                comperator: {type: String, enum: ['lte', 'gte', 'bw', 'eq']},
                subject_id: ObjectId,
                value_0: Number,
                value_1: Number
            })]
})
```

now i want to find all campaigns where the values from the user match with the filters of the campaign. the user schema is defined as the following:

```
new MongoOse.Schema({
username: String,
subject: ObjectId,
curr_avg: Number,
target_avg: Number
})
```

Any Ideas on how I can run a `collection.find()` query to get the matching campaigns for the user?

My first draft is the following:

```
{$or: [
                                {
                                    filters: // todo: find matching documents
                                },
                                {
                                    filters: {
                                        $size: 0 // or no filters specified
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    filters: null
                                }, {
                                    filters: {
                                        $exists: false // or filters not exisiting
                                    }
                                }
                            ]}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a level of abstraction that I don't think you need. Why are you creating a filters attribute? With MongoDB, attributes ARE the filters... remove that layer and just use `Campaign.find({'field': 'value', 'field2': 'value2'});`

Also - using type as an attribute name is probably not advisable.

Comment: Hi Michael, well not really. the filters save for example that the campaign is relevant for users with `curr_avg` greater than. this can not be stored in a simple field.